# How do i simulate keypresses in lua after mouse 1 is pressed?

Tags: lua, macros, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

im trying to simulate a sequence of keypresses in lua, i already have it working with another program but im limited to it being always on or off instead of being able to toggle it with capslock. but im getting the error `"[string "LuaVM"]:8: attempt to call a nil value (global 'Keypress') Line Number:1"`
this is my current code which i copied the base from another known working macro without errors. not really sure where to go from here or how to debug it, ive already tried searching the error in google but cant find anything useful

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end
     if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
        if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED") then
            Sleep(50)
            Keypress(114)
            Sleep(250)
            Keypress(50)
            Sleep(50)
            Keypress(49)
          end
        end
      end
```

this is the original donor code i tried to use

```
    function OnEvent(event, arg)
        if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
            EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
        end
     if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
        if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1)then
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(-10, 10)
            Sleep(10)
            MoveMouseRelative(10, -10)
            Sleep(10)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            end
          end
        end
      end
```

final code

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end
     if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            Sleep(10)
            PressAndReleaseKey("R")
            Sleep(95)
            PressAndReleaseKey("2")
            Sleep(10)
            PressAndReleaseKey("1")
          end
       end
     end
```

Comment: `PressAndReleaseKey(string.char(114))` for key `R`.  Numbers in `PressAndReleaseKey` means keyboard scan-codes, not ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

https://douile.com/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf Page 14

It's `PressKey`, not `Keypress`.